# Can we provide a canonical question&answer for Haskell's monomorphism restriction?

Tags: discussion, canonical

I follow a bit the [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) tag and I **often** see questions like:

- [Transforming a function to point-free style changes its type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052670/transforming-a-function-to-point-free-style-changes-its-type?lq=1)
- [Why does Haskell point free version of function result in ambiguous type error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181658/why-does-haskell-pointless-version-of-function-result-in-ambiguous-type-error)
- [Why do 3 and x (which was assigned 3) have different inferred types in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055146/why-do-3-and-x-which-was-assigned-3-have-different-inferred-types-in-haskell?rq=1)
- [Avoiding monomorphism in let bindings without type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657475/avoiding-monomorphism-in-let-bindings-without-type-annotation/14657595)
- [Type of a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942957/type-of-a-double/23942989)
- [Cannot assign in haskell prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288266/cannot-assign-in-haskell-prompt/18289681)
- [Trivial parsec example produces a type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723208/trivial-parsec-example-produces-a-type-error)
- [Haskell types error: Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590180/haskell-types-error-inferred-type-is-less-polymorphic-than-expected/11590218)
- [Partial application and sortBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218610/partial-application-and-sortby/24218682)
- [Strange Haskell type error only happening when currying assertEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058716/strange-haskell-type-error-only-happening-when-currying-assertequal/7058944)
- [let expression in do causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460019/let-expression-in-do-causes-error/7460097)
- [Haskell partial application doesn't seem to work with on. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942946/haskell-partial-application-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-on-why/22943070)
- [Why is it that sometimes defining a value in Haskell changes its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105691/why-is-it-that-sometimes-defining-a-value-in-haskell-changes-its-type/30105781)
- [Differences between a line in a haskell source file and one in GHCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823642/differences-between-a-line-in-a-haskell-source-file-and-one-in-ghci/21823889)
- [Haskell function composition confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470682/haskell-function-composition-confusion/20470889)
- [Alias for a function name has a different type signature. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320189/haskell-alias-for-a-function-name-has-a-different-type-signature-why/6320243)
- [Making new Monad Cont with ContT Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934042/making-new-monad-cont-with-contt-constructor/28934198)
- [Understanding why a/b doesn't work, but fromInteger a / fromInteger b does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244612/understanding-why-a-b-doesnt-work-but-frominteger-a-frominteger-b-does/16244710)
- [Haskell: !! operator on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918250/haskell-operator-on-variable/23918342)
- [What make the difference between `:t` and let expression in GHCi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816416/what-make-the-difference-between-t-and-let-expression-in-ghci/21816473)
- [Int literal in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984233/int-literal-in-haskell/22984306)
- [Foldr compare acc to empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472318/foldr-compare-acc-to-empty-list/10472408)
- [Evaluation, let and where in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748388/evaluation-let-and-where-in-haskell/24748444)
- [Type signatures for Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941341/type-signatures-for-values/15949039)
- [Monomorphism restriction in pattern bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400980/monomorphism-restriction-in-pattern-bindings/26401230)
- [Strange type-related error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926664/strange-type-related-error/2926809)
- [Strange type-related error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926664/strange-type-related-error/2926809)
- [Type error while writing max function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036701/type-error-while-writing-max-function/20036837)
- [Why would Haskell infer a specific type (apparently) inconsistently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117965/why-would-haskell-infer-a-specific-type-apparently-inconsistently/10118039)
- [Function substitution with an import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794660/function-substitution-with-an-import/27794695)
- [GHCi ignores type signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193338/ghci-ignores-type-signature/29193692)
- [Let-renaming function breaks code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724738/let-renaming-function-breaks-code/24725212)
- [Why does `let foo = (fmap . const)` fail with "No instance for (Functor f0) arising from a use of `fmap'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457140/why-does-let-foo-fmap-const-fail-with-no-instance-for-functor-f0-aris/24457250)
- [Type inference of a function in GHCi differs with loaded from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379830/type-inference-of-a-function-in-ghci-differs-with-loaded-from-a-file/25380017)
- [Why does signature change after an assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451501/why-does-signature-change-after-an-assignment/15451793)
- [Does flip alter the parameter data types of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834670/does-flip-alter-the-parameter-data-types-of-functions/24834691)
- [What is XNoMonomorphismRestriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575040/what-is-xnomonomorphismrestriction/4575079)
- [GHC: Why does type ambiguity go away when using let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195242/ghc-why-does-type-ambiguity-go-away-when-using-let/26198308)
- [Why Doesn't Haskell Generalize Some Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254447/why-doesnt-haskell-generalize-some-functions/19254511)
- [Specific type inference using uncurry function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999020/specific-type-inference-using-uncurry-function/4999860)

*All* these question share the same answer:

> It's the [dreaded monomorphism
>   restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction).
>   Bindings of the type `x = ...` are forced to be monomorphic unless you
>   provide a type signature.
>
> You can disallow the behaviour by using the
>   `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension by putting:
>
> ```hs
> {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
> ```
>
> at the top of your file or compiling with the flag
>   `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`.

I know that having the same answer doesn't imply that the questions are duplicate, yet looking at all those question I don't think that having many different answers and questions is a good thing.

What I see is that the information about the issue is spread across many different questions, which are generally very hard to search effectively, and the answer they obtain are fundamentally identical in their basic information, yet most answer miss some aspect or information that would be useful.

I propose to create (or find an existing) canonical question regarding the issue and provide a *thorough* answer (probably taking information and examples from the HaskellWiki) and close all other questions as duplicates of this one.

The next time a new question is asked where the answer would be "it's due to the monomorphism restriction + link to HaskellWiki", instead of answering vote to close as a duplicate of the canonical question.

In this way everyone will see the most complete and useful answer, instead of receive only part of the information about the issue.

I believe the canonical answer ought to:

- explain what the monomorphism restriction is and when it is triggered (with a few examples, taken from the wiki or the linked questions above)
- how to avoid it (type signatures, pragma and compilation flag)
- difference between ghci and ghc
- what changed with new versions of haskell and ghc/ghci

Reading at the answers and questions above I couldn't find any existing answer that contains all the above information.

Comment: It looks like you worked out most of the details needed for that post. What's keeping you from posting it?

Comment: @Cerbrus Before doing it I'd like to hear at least some opinions from those who follow the tag. Having a canonical Q&A is useless if nobody is going to actually use it and reference it. Also, I believe there are people that would produce a better explanation than mine.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense :-)

Comment: You might consider making your current proposed canonical answer a community wiki answer to this meta question to more easily allow other collaboration.  It also has the benefit of separating the meta votes for "I think we need a canonical Q&A" from the meta votes for "I think this answer is a good canonical answer"

Comment: @ryanyuyu Okay, I'm doing it now.

Comment: "I know that having the same answer doesn't imply that the questions are duplicate ... I propose to create (or find an existing) canonical question ... and close all other questions as duplicates of this one." So you acknowledge that it isn't a duplicate yet you try to close other questions as being a duplicate? That sounds like abuse. As I mentioned in one of the questions you marked as a duplicate, the question you created presupposes that the asker already knows the answer to their question. Knowing what MR is doesn't make it obvious that it's the cause of your trouble when you run into it.

Comment: Questions should only be marked as duplicate if they actually are duplicates. In this case, what you should really be doing is adding a "See also" link to your "canonical answer" in each of the "It's the dreaded monomorphism restriction" answers (either in a comment or in an answer itself).

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves You had **4 months** to provide feedback here if you didn't agree. Moreover what I meant is that **maybe** not **all** of such questions could be considered duplicates but **most are duplicates** (just renaming a variable in the code or changing an `Int` to a`Double` doesn't make your question not a duplicate). Moreover in **all cases** I believe that having a single pointer with *all* the information well organized is better than having to search for tens of different pointers and try to rearrange all information in your head.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Regarding your quesiton: that's exactly what I'd call a *perfect duplicate*. Besides the answer is one of the least helpful I found, barely stating the name of the issue and mentioning how to turn the restriction off without any sort of explanation.  Note that if you read carefully the answer I posted you'll find that it answer all the points in your question.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Final point: I'm a bit offended that you say this is an "abuse". As I already mentioned I opened this meta question before posting that question&answer. I did so *4 months ago* and I asked if *somebody* (not me) would do that. People told me "just do it yourself". I've repeteadly asked on chat etc for feedback and all the feedback I got was "go ahead, that's good stuff". Moreover note that I don't have a dupe-hammer for haskell so I can only provide one close vote. If people disagree the question wont be closed. No harm done (plus this already adds the link).

Comment: Are you really trying to say that the fact that you posted this 4 months ago means it's too late for people to criticize your plan now? I'm feeling a bit like Arthur Dent here. You had far longer to mark many of those questions as duplicates (sometimes **years**) so by your own reasoning it's too late for you to complain about them now.

Comment: Many of the questions you attempted to close as duplicate (including mine) aren't duplicates of your question *at all*, because the questions don't even know that MR is a factor. A question cannot duplicate a separate question that presupposes the answer.  It's like if you went to the doctor and started telling her your symptoms and she cuts you off and says "just tell me what you've got and I'll tell you the treatment". The question should discuss only symptoms and the answer then provides diagnosis and treatment.

Comment: Do you think it would make sense for someone to post a question "What is Haskell?" along with a copy of *The Haskell 98 Language Report* as an answer, and then close every question that could be answered by a careful reading of the report (including your question "What is the monomorphism restriction?") as a duplicate? What you're doing isn't far off from that.

Comment: If you really want to consolidate the MR questions, a better approach would be to group the questions that are similar, and post a generalized question for each group. I feel like I'm restating the obvious here, but the monomorphism restriction should not even be *mentioned* in the *question*, as that presupposes the answer.  Only the *answer* should talk about MR. If you want to have the answers to these questions link to your "What is the monomorphism restriction?" question, then that sounds great.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves I didn't say that it's too late. Just that you cannot come here without reading anything and accuse me of abuse. I also disagree with your reasoning. To me the case of MR is the same as (e.g.) "the mutable default argument in python". The question is simply missing the formal name. What happens in that case is that whenever someone post the *millionth* question with a `def f(x=[])` it is "insta-closed" to avoid that people loose time answer that when all the information is already on SO.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Besides, note that I did **not** vote to close all the question I listed above (which again debunks your "you are abusing" claim). I decided to mark a few. The authors or others are free to decide whether that's the case or not.  I'll surely vote to close all *new* questions though.

Comment: "Mutable default argument" is a description of the symptom. "Hey, my default arguments values are mutating. Why are my default arguments mutable?" It makes sense as the question. Monomorphism restriction is a diagnosis, not a symptom. Symptoms would be things like "Why is Haskell claiming that this sub-expression is ambiguous when I factor it out into a variable?" How would the person asking that question rewrite that as "What is MR?" without already knowing the answer to their own question?

Comment: If I came here "without reading anything", how did I quote where you yourself stated "I know that having the same answer doesn't imply that the questions are duplicate"? I suggest you go back and read what I said. You seem to take a lot of offense at me pointing out that marking questions as a duplicate of something that one knows is not a duplicate "sounds like abuse". You also seem to be digging you heels in with what any reasonable person would know is an losing argument. "What is MR?" is not a duplicate of any question that doesn't know that MR is the cause of the symptoms from the outset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted the question & a modified version of the below answer at: [What is the monomorphism restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/510937)

---

I took some time to draft a possible answer. I'd like to have any inputs on it.

- Is there anything missing or wrong in it?
- Is there some unclear passage?
- Should I add something else? While the answer should satisfy new users giving also a high level description of the problem and how to fix it, I also want to provide an in-depth explanation for those who want to understand what's at work. I'm even considering adding a bit of explanation about unification and how type inferencing is done so that readers can really get a feeling of what's happening. Would this be too much?

If there's already an answer that contains the information above I'd like to know about it, so that we can use that instead (and eventually improve it).

I made this answer CW as suggested so that you can more easily edit it. Feel free to provide your improvements. If this answer receive some attention and upvotes in the ~next week (say till 6 September) I'll post it as a CW question & answer.

---

## What is the monomorphism restriction?

The [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) as stated by the Haskell wiki is:

> a counter-intuitive rule in Haskell type inference.
>   If you forget to provide a type signature, sometimes this rule will fill
>   the free type variables with specific types using "type defaulting" rules.

What this means is that, *in some circumstances*, if your type is ambiguous (i.e. polymorphic) the compiler will choose to *instantiate* that type to something not ambiguous.

#### An example

Take the following trivial definition:

```
plus = (+)
```

you'd think to be able to replace every occurrence of `+` with `plus`. In particular since `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` you'd expect to also have `plus :: Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Unfortunately this is not the case. For example in we try the following in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let plus = (+)
Prelude> plus 1.0 1
```

We get the following output:

```
<interactive>:4:6:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from the literal ‘1.0’
    In the first argument of ‘plus’, namely ‘1.0’
    In the expression: plus 1.0 1
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = plus 1.0 1
```

<sup>You may need to `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction`  in newer GHCi versions.</sup>

And in fact we can see that the type of `plus` is not what we would expect:

```
Prelude> :t plus
plus :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

What happened is that the compiler saw that `plus` had type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, a polymorphic type. Moreover it happens that the above definition falls under the rules that I'll explain later and so he decided to make the type monomorphic by *defaulting* the type variable `a`. The default is `Integer` as we can see.

#### Some other example

Consider the following definitions:

```
f1 x = show x

f2 = \x -> show x

f3 :: (Show a) => a -> String
f3 = \x -> show x

f4 = show

f5 :: (Show a) => a -> String
f5 = show
```

We'd expect all these functions to behave in the same way and have the same type, i.e. the type of `show`: `Show a => a -> String`.

Yet:

- `f1` is okay.
- `f2` has type `() -> String`.
- `f3` is okay.
- `f4` has again type `() -> String`
- `f5` is okay.

Monomorphism restriction is what makes `f2` and `f4` have that strange type. If you have declarations like the `f2` and `f4` or `plus` in your program you'll probably have some trouble with this restriction.

<sup>Note that this last example isn't actually Haskell 2010 compliant. According to the Haskell 2010 report only numeric types can be defaulted and so you'd get a type error instead of a defaulting to `()`.</sup>

## How do I fix it?

First of all you can always explicitly provide a type signature and this will avoid the triggering of the restriction:

```
plus :: Num a => a -> a -> a
plus = (+)    -- Okay!

-- Runs as:
Prelude> plus 1.0 1
2.0
```

Alternatively, if you are defining a function, you can *avoid* [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree), and for example write:

```
plus x y = x + y
```

### Turning it off

It is possible to simply turn off the restriction so that you don't have to do anything to your code to fix it. The behaviour is controlled by two extensions: `MonomorphismRestriction` will enable it (which is the default) while `NoMonomorphismRestriction` will disable it.

You can put the following line at the very top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

If you are using GHCi you can enable the extension using the `:set` command:

```
Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

You can also tell `ghc` to enable the extension from the command line:

```
ghc ... -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

**Note:** You should really prefer the first option over choosing extension via command-line options.

Refer to [GHC's page](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#monomorphism) for an explanation of this and other extensions.

## When does it happen?

In Haskell, as defined by the [report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/), there are *two* distinct type of [*bindings*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-830004.4.3). Function bindings and pattern bindings. A function binding is nothing else than a definition of a function:

```
f x = x + 1
```

Note that their syntax is:

```
<identifier> arg1 arg2 ... argn = expr
```

<sup>Modulo guards and `where` declarations. But they don't really matter.</sup>

where there must be *at least one argument*.

A pattern binding is a declaration of the form:

```
<pattern> = expr
```

<sup>Again, modulo guards.</sup>

Note that *variables are patterns*, so the binding:

```
plus = (+)
```

is a *pattern* binding. It's binding the pattern `plus` (a variable) to the expression `(+)`.

When a pattern binding consists of only a variable name it's called a
*simple* pattern binding.

**The monomorphism restriction applies to simple pattern bindings!**

Well, formally we should say that:

> *A declaration group* is a minimal set of mutually dependent bindings.

<sup>Section 4.5.1 of the [report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).</sup>

And then (Section 4.5.5 of the [report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/)):

> a given declaration group is *unrestricted* if and only if:
>
> 1. every variable in the group is bound by a function binding (e.g. `f x = x`)
>      or a simple pattern binding (e.g. `plus = (+)`; Section 4.4.3.2 ), and
> 2. an explicit type signature is given for every variable in the group that
>      is bound by simple pattern binding. (e.g. `plus :: Num a => a -> a -> a; plus = (+)`).

<sup>Examples added by me.</sup>

So a *restricted* declaration group is a group where, either there are
*non-simple* pattern bindings (e.g. `(x:xs) = f something` or `(f, g) = ((+), (-))`) or there is some simple pattern binding without a type signature (as in `plus = (+)`).

*The monomorphism restriction affects **restricted** declaration groups.*

Most of the time you don't define mutual recursive functions and hence a declaration group becomes just *a* binding.

## What does it do?

The monomorphism restriction is described by two rules in Section
4.5.5 of the [report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).

### First rule

> The usual Hindley-Milner restriction on polymorphism is that only type
>   variables that do not occur free in the environment may be generalized.
>   In addition, **the constrained type variables of a restricted declaration
>   group may not be generalized in the generalization step for that group.**
>   (Recall that a type variable is constrained if it must belong to some
>   type class; see Section 4.5.2 .)

The highlighted part is what the monomorphism restriction introduces. It says that *if* the type is polymorphic (i.e. it contain some type variable)
*and* that type variable is constrained (i.e. it has a class constraint on it: e.g. the type `Num a => a -> a -> a` is polymorphic because it contains `a` and also contrained because the `a` has the constraint `Num` over it.)
*then* it cannot be generalized.

In simple words *not generalizing* means that the **uses** of the function `plus` may change its type.

If you had the definitions:

```
plus = (+)

x :: Integer
x = plus 1 2

y :: Double
y = plus 1.0 2
```

then you'd get a type error. Because when the compiler sees that `plus` is called over an `Integer` in the declaration of `x` it will unify the type variable `a` with `Integer` and hence the type of `plus` becomes:

```
Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

but then, when it will type check the definition of `y`, it will see that `plus` is applied to a `Double` argument, and the types don't match.

Note that you can still use `plus` without getting an error:

```
plus = (+)
x = plus 1.0 2
```

In this case the type of `plus` is first inferred to be `Num a => a -> a -> a` but then its use in the definition of `x`, where `1.0` requires a `Fractional` constraint, will change it to `Fractional a => a -> a -> a`.

#### Rationale

The report says:

> Rule 1 is required for two reasons, both of which are fairly subtle.
>
> - Rule 1 prevents computations from being unexpectedly repeated.
>     For example, `genericLength` is a standard function (in library `Data.List`)
>     whose type is given by
>
>   ```
>   genericLength :: Num a => [b] -> a
>   ```
>
>   Now consider the following expression:
>
>   ```
>   let len = genericLength xs
>   in (len, len)
>   ```
>
>   It looks as if `len` should be computed only once, but **without Rule 1 it
>     might be computed twice, once at each of two different overloadings.**
>     If the programmer does actually wish the computation to be repeated,
>     an explicit type signature may be added:
>
>   ```
>   let len :: Num a => a
>       len = genericLength xs
>   in (len, len)
>   ```

For this point the example from the [wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) is, I believe, clearer. Consider the function:

```
f xs = (len, len)
  where
    len = genericLength xs
```

If `len` was polymorphic the type of `f` would be:

```
f :: Num a, Num b => [c] -> (a, b)
```

So the two elements of the tuple `(len, len)` could actually be
*different* values! But this means that the computation done by `genericLength` *must* be repeated to obtain the two different values.

The rationale here is: the code contains *one* function call, but not introducing this rule could produce *two* hidden function calls, which is counter intuitive.

With the monomorphism restriction the type of `f` becomes:

```
f :: Num a => [b] -> (a, a)
```

In this way there is no need to perform the computation multiple times.

> - Rule 1 prevents ambiguity. For example, consider the declaration group
>
>   [(n,s)] = reads t
>
>   Recall that `reads` is a standard function whose type is given by the signature
>
>   reads :: (Read a) => String -> [(a,String)]
>
>   Without Rule 1, `n` would be assigned the type `∀ a. Read a  ⇒  a` and `s`
>     the type `∀ a. Read a ⇒  String`.
>     The latter is an invalid type, because it is inherently ambiguous.
>     It is not possible to determine at what overloading to use `s`,
>     nor can this be solved by adding a type signature for `s`.
>     Hence, when non-simple pattern bindings are used (Section 4.4.3.2 ),
>     the types inferred are always monomorphic in their constrained type variables,
>     irrespective of whether a type signature is provided.
>     In this case, both `n` and `s` are monomorphic in `a`.

Well, I believe this example is self-explanatory. There are situations when not applying the rule results in type ambiguity.

If you disable the extension as suggest above you *will* get a type error when trying to compile the above declaration. However this isn't really a problem: you already know that when using `read` you have to somehow tell the compiler which type it should try to parse...

### Second rule

> 2. Any monomorphic type variables that remain when type inference for an
>      entire module is complete, are considered ambiguous, and are resolved
>      to particular types using the defaulting rules (Section 4.3.4 ).

This means that. If you have your usual definition:

```
plus = (+)
```

This will have a type `Num a => a -> a -> a` where `a` is a
*monomorphic* type variable due to rule 1 described above. Once the whole module is inferred the compiler will simply choose a type that will replace that `a` according to the defaulting rules.

The final result is: `plus :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`.

Note that this is done *after* the whole module is inferred.

This means that if you have the following declarations:

```
plus = (+)

x = plus 1.0 2.0
```

inside a module, *before* type defaulting the type of `plus` will be: `Fractional a => a -> a -> a` (see rule 1 for why this happens). At this point, following the defaulting rules, `a` will be replaced by `Double` and so we will have `plus :: Double -> Double -> Double` and `x :: Double`.

## Defaulting

As stated before there exist some *defaulting* rules, described in [Section 4.3.4 of the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), that the inferencer can adopt and that will replace a polymorphic type with a monomorphic one. This happens whenever a type is *ambiguous*.

For example in the expression:

```
let x = read "<something>" in show x
```

here the expression is ambiguous because the types for `show` and `read` are:

```
show :: Show a => a -> String
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

So the `x` has type `Read a => a`. But this constraint is satisfied by a lot of types: `Int`, `Double` or `()` for example. Which one to choose? There's nothing that can tell us.

In this case we can resolve the ambiguity by telling the compiler which type we want, adding a type signature:

```
let x = read "<something>" :: Int in show x
```

Now the problem is: since Haskell uses the `Num` type class to handle numbers, there are *a lot* of cases where numerical expressions contain ambiguities.

Consider:

```
show 1
```

What should the result be?

As before `1` has type `Num a => a` and there are many type of numbers that could be used. Which one to choose?

Having a compiler error almost every time we use a number isn't a good thing, and hence the defaulting rules were introduced. The rules can be controlled using a `default` declaration. By specifying `default (T1, T2, T3)` we can change how the inferencer defaults the different types.

An ambiguous type variable `v` is defaultable if:

- `v` appears only in contraints of the kind `C v` were `C` is a class
  (i.e. if it appears as in: `Monad (m v)` then it is **not** defaultable).
- at least one of these classes is `Num` or a subclass of `Num`.
- all of these classes are defined in the Prelude or a standard library.

A defaultable type variable is replaced by the *first* type in the `default` list that is an instance of all the ambiguous variable’s classes.

The default `default` declaration is `default (Integer, Double)`.

For example:

```
plus = (+)
minus = (-)

x = plus 1.0 1
y = minus 2 1
```

The types inferred would be:

```
plus :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
minus :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

which, by defaulting rules, become:

```
plus :: Double -> Double -> Double
minus :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

#### Extended defaulting

Note that GHCi comes with [*extended* defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules), which can be enabled in files as well using the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extensions.

The defaultable type variables need not *only* appear in contraints where all the classes are standard and there must be at least one class that is among `Eq`, `Ord`, `Show` or `Num` and its subclasses.

Moreover the default `default` declaration is `default ((), Integer, Double)`.

#### Useful links

There are *a lot* of resources and discussions about the monomorphism restriction.

Here are some links that I find useful and that may help you understand or deep further into the topic:

- Haskell's wiki page: [Monomorphism Restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction)
- The [report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/)
- An accessible and nice [blog post](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/05/towards-understanding-haskells-monomorphism-restriction/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe all of these questions should be considered duplicates. I think the question is not a duplicate when:

- the monomorphism restriction is applied when a user function's type is related to a non-trivial type from a library in such a way that it is not immediately obvious what the correct type is, and
- the library in question is a commonly-used one which is being used in a common way, and therefore other users are likely to see an identical error

In such a case the correct answer is to indicate what type signature is required, along with a clarification that this is required due to the monomorphism restriction and preferably a link to the canonical answer above. See [Trivial parsec example produces a type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723208/trivial-parsec-example-produces-a-type-error) for an example of such a question.